# Strange black line under Wordpress logo

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am building my own website using Wordpress. When I was using a PNG picture(140*82 px) instead of the default "site-title" as my site logo, I got a really strange result. The picture is presented nicely, but there is a black line just under the picture. I have checked my "header.php" and "style.css" file, nothing wrong there. I also used Chrome "Inspector" to check the logo, it said: img 140*83( natural 140*82 ).

So, where does this line come from? Thanks, guys!

Here is my logo section in "header.php":

```
<<?php echo $heading_tag; ?> id="site-title">
    <span>
        <a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>.com" rel="home"> <img src="http://118.228.173.234/wp-content/uploads/logo.png" width = "140" height = "82"> </a>
    </span>
</<?php echo $heading_tag; ?>>
```

Comment: You can use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to inspect the HTML content, and find exactly where this line is coming from.

Comment: I'm not a pro at Wordpress but the extra `<` in `<<?php echo $heading_tag; ?>` doesn't make sense. Also the extra `>` and `</` in `</<?php echo $heading_tag; ?>>` - I could very well be wrong.

Comment: Oops, I changed, but more things went wrong...

Comment: I tried accessing `http://118.228.173.234/wp-content/uploads/logo.png` and it's not loading. Is that the actual URL to the image?

Comment: I'm in my University, my school has blocked some kinds of connection from out side of the school (also wish someone can help me with this), I guess. But it works on my machine.

Comment: Another thing you can try and this has posed a problem for me in the past are, the "spaces" before and after your image `<img src="http://118.228.173.234/wp-content/uploads/logo.png" width = "140" height = "82">` between `rel="home"> <img src=` and `height = "82"> </a>`

Comment: For "testing purposes" while working with a "copy" of your header.php file, try only having `<?php echo $heading_tag; ?>` and `<?php echo $heading_tag; ?>` while keeping the rest of your code intact. I also suggest you remove the spaces in your `width = "140" height = "82"` - there shouldn't be any spaces around the `=` signs.

Comment: I think you do need the "extra" angle brackets, as I'm pretty sure `$heading_tag` has a value of `div` or `header`, etc.

Comment: This may be relevant or silly, but any possibility that the graphic itself has the black line at the bottom? (process of elimination) have to cover all the bases.

Comment: @Fred The picture has no problem, I'm sure with that. I also tried your suggestions, but that line is still there, and even more, it will extent itself while the picture's width extends.

Comment: @ultranaut If I add an extra bracket, there will be actually a real ">" in the html.

Comment: @yuhao it's gotta be CSS related then. Check if you have reference to `span` in your CSS and locate the black `#000` or `#000000`. Hard to tell without seeing more code at this point. Check for `#site-title` in CSS also.

Comment: @Fred Wow, this method is brilliant! I just searched "#000" to find any place that is suspicious. And I noticed there is a "border-bottom 1px " for every"img" in <branding> which is supposed to only work for the big header picture. And that's the criminal! Thanks, to you, and everybody!

Comment: @yuhao That's great! I will post as an answer then you can mark as "answered", cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's gotta be CSS related then. Check if you have reference to span in your CSS and locate the black #000 or #000000. Hard to tell without seeing more code at this point. Check for #site-title in CSS also.